# IBM DB2 - IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ, IBMSNAP_COMMITSEQ

Tags: db2, replication

I am trying to perform an incremental (delta) extraction from a mainframe replicated (IBM SQL REPLICATION) table.  The table contains 2 ibm columns IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ and IBMSNAP_COMMITSEQ which are defined as VARCHAR () FOR BIT DATA.

I was told that IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ is unique for transaction and ascending.  I stored the HEX(IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ) and use this for next pull.  example.  select * from ccd01_sku where HEX(IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ) > '00D3B07F81F9C7000000000000000009' (obtained from max of previous run).

Is this reliable.  Anyone having experience with IBM Replication CCD tables Please?

Thanks,

SD

Answer (score 0):

We are using this way of processing reliably for more than half a year now. To our knowledge, IBMSNAP_INTENTSEQ is indeed unique and ascending.